# Проблема с AJAX и PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Не выполняется условие в php, при отправке AJAX запроса, хотя поле было заполнено

```html
<form>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" autocomplete=off>
    </p>
    <button class="auth" value="button">Войти</button>
    <div class="error"></div>
</form>
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const login = document.querySelector('input[name="login"]').value;
    const error = document.querySelector('.error');
    const form_auth = new XMLHttpRequest();
    form_auth.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            error.innerText = '';
            if (login.length < 3) {
                error.innerText = 'Ошибка в логине';
            }
        }
    }
    form_auth.open('GET', `index.php?login=${login}`);
    form_auth.send();
});
```

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["login"])) {
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Попробуй ажахсом отправить, + `echo($_GET["login"]);` ++ `exit();` после echo

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: 1. `encodeURIComponent` потерялся. 2. Адрес страницы проверь. 3. Проверять длину после отправки запроса уже как-то поздновато.

Comment: @ doox911, друг, там гет) а автору советую перед if `var_dump($_GET)`, и почему гет в данном случае, отправляйте post.

Comment: Ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогает. Условие оказывается срабатывает, например в БД я могу отправить запрос, но вот вывод на экран(echo, print_r и т.д.) не работает